# PHP & Jquery - Set row status as approved/pending via modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

My status column should read Approved or Pending per user row. Upon click of edit  button, at bottom of modal should say current status and Yes/No radio buttons to keep as is or change status, and have that reflected in the table.

Right now it's only setting to Pending in the modal upon selecting No, and I need the same logic but upon click of Yes for Approved. Help!

PHP Function:n

```
public function approve(){
    $id = $this->input->get("user_id"); 
    $this->db->where("id", $id); 
    $data = [
        "approved" => 1
    ]; 
    if (isset($data['approved']) && $data['approved'] == 1) {
        $this->db->update("User_Inputs", $data); 
        redirect("/myform/getdatabase"); 
    }
    else {
        echo 0;
}
```

HTML/JQuery:

```
     <html>
     <head>    
        <title>Admin View</title>    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     </head>

     <body background=http://wallpapercave.com/wp/ItmVuT6.jpg>

        <!-- container with table headers / user records / edit function / approve function -->    
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                <center>
                    <thead> 
                        <tr style="font-size: 24; color: white;">
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th colspan="1">Action</th>        
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </center>

                <tbody style="background-color: #F0F8FF">   
                    <?php         
                    foreach($users as $u)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <tr style="font-size: 20;" id="row<?= $u->id?>">
                            <td width="5%;"> <?php echo $u->id; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $u->first_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $u->last_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $u->email; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo ($u->approved) ? "Approved" : "Pending"; ?></td>

                            <!--edit button-->
                            <td><button type="button" data-id="<?= $u->id ?>" data-first_name="<?= $u->first_name ?>" data-last_name="<?= $u->last_name ?>" data-email="<?= $u->email ?>" data-approved="<?= $u->approved ?>" onclick="loadmodal(this)"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span></button></td> 

                            <!--approve button
                            <td><a href= "/ci/index.php/myform/approve/?user_id=<?php echo $u->id;?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok gi-15x" style='color: green'></span></a></td>-->

                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody> 
                </table>

<!--modal-->
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadmodal(button){
    var first_name = $(button).data("first_name"); 
    var last_name = $(button).data("last_name"); 
    var email = $(button).data("email"); 
    var id = $(button).data("id"); 
    var status = $(button).data("approved");


    /* pass values to modal */
    $("#m_id").val(id);
    $("#m_first_name").val(first_name); 
    $("#m_last_name").val(last_name); 
    $("#m_email").val(email);
    $("#m_approved").val(status); 
    $("input[name=r1]:checked").val()
    $("input[name=r2]:checked").val()
    $("#myModalLabel").text("Entry for User ID: " + id);

    $("#editModal").modal("show"); 

    $("#formdata").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var data = $(this).serialize(); 

        $.post("/ci/index.php/myform/edituser", data, function(html){
            console.log(html); 
            var response = $.parseJSON(html);
            console.log(response);  
            if (response.status == 'success'){
                    $("#row"+id).html(response.html); 
                    $("#editModal").modal("hide"); 
            } else {
                    console.log('Error updating user'); 
                    $("#editModal").modal("hide"); 
            }  
        });  
    });



function approveRadio(){
    if (document.getElementsByID('r1').checked) {
        rate_value = document.getElementsByID
    }
    var choice = document.getElementsByName('choice').value;

}
}
</script>
            <div class='modal fade' id='editModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'> 
                        <div class='modal-dialog'> 
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                        <div class='modal-header'>
                                            <h3 class="modal-title" id='myModalLabel'></h3>
                                                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label="Close"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>
                                        </div>

                                <!--modal body-->
                                    <div class='modal-body'>
                                            <form id="formdata">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="m_id" name="id" value="">
                                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                                            <label class='control-label' for='First Name'>First Name</label> 
                                                                <input type='text' id="m_first_name" name='first_name' class='form-control' 
                                                                value=""><br/>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                                            <label class='control-label' for='Last Name'>Last Name</label>
                                                            <input type='text' id="m_last_name" name='last_name' class='form-control' value=""/><br/>
                                                    </div> 

                                                    <div class='form-group'> 
                                                            <label class='control-label' for='Last Name'>Email</label>
                                                            <input type='text' id="m_email" name='email' class='form-control' value=""/><br/>
                                                    </div>


                                                    <div class='form-group'> 
                                                            <label class='control-label' for='Approved'>Is user approved? Current status:</label><br>
                                                            <input type="radio" id="r1" name="approved" value="1"> Yes 
                                                            <input type="radio" id="r2" name="approved" value="0"> No
                                                            <!--m<input type="text" id="m_approved" name="status" class='form-control' value="">-->
                                                    </div>

                                                    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'>Update Entry</button>

                                                </form>
                                        </div>              
                                </div>
                </div> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no input[name=r1] and input[name=r2] in your form

Comment: explain please!

Comment: What are you trying with these $("input[name=r1]:checked").val() and    $("input[name=r2]:checked").val(), because there is no input available whose name is r1 and r2

Comment: is it opossivle for me to check id instead of name, foe example input[id=r1]:checked.val()?

Comment: You are trying to check the respective radio input based on your status, am I right ?

Comment: correct! i want the admin to be able to answer Yes or No vai the unqiue radio buttons in the modal to set the status of th user row in the table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144187/discussion-between-mr-jibz-and-sk-jajoriya).